# How can I "unclick" a button in C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-6

I have a button in C++ Builder 6 that I need to activate (and stay activated). But when I don't need it anymore, I want to click again on that button, and it goes back to the UP state.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're working with VCL controls I think you can use a `TSpeedButton` and implement the toggle logic with its `TSpeedButton.Down` property. It stays pressed while Down is true and unpressed when Down is false. [Check this](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Buttons_TSpeedButton_Down.html)

there are these properties for this:

- `TSpeedButton::Down` indicates clicked button (you can also programaticaly set it to true/false on runtime)
- `TSpeedButton::AllowUp` enable unclicking on second click
- `TSpeedButton::GroupIndex` if non zero all buttons with the same index are goruped together and only one can be down at time so when you click on one all others are unclicked.

So for single button set `AllowUp=true` And `GroupIndex` to unique non zero number and for multiple buttons just set `GroupIndex` to the same unique non zero number for all buttons.

Cheers!